# Parse Order: how to pass a value from PI as an embed variable?

Tags: templates, parse-order, parsing

I have a plugin that outputs a value, which I ***think*** I need to pass as an embed variable as I need to use that value as a parameter when calling the plugin again from within the embed. Here's the basic structure:

```
{exp:my_plugin)
     {embed="foo/bar" my_plugin_value="{some_value_from_my_plugin}"}
{/exp:my_plugin)
```

In the embedded template, `{embed:my_plugin_value}` is empty. I have double checked to make sure the value is indeed set before calling the embed. Am I running into parse issues? If so, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's two plugin tags that you are needing to nest, see [changing parse order](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order) for nested tags using the `parse="inward"` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

Try testing your parameter logic for your plugin to ensure you're properly retrieving the parameter value.

If that's not the issue try passing a string into the embed to see if it's in fact an issue with the embed variable.